# Should profiling be done on selected platforms or on all the platforms?

Tags: c++, profile

Suppose I am developing a general library for multiple platforms: linux, windows, mac, ios and Android. After the library passes the functionality test, in order to improve its performance profiling the library is needed. Then my question is: should i profile it on each different platforms or can I select the most familiar platform and then perform the profiling?

Comment: To get meaningful results, you probably need to profile on more than one target. If the code is CPU bound, for example, then you just about need to profile on every target CPU, and work at balancing your results--it'll rarely be optimal on any one CPU, but you want to avoid its being horrible on any CPU either.

Comment: If your product is cross-platform, you should do a cross-platform profiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on what type of optimizations you are planning and how important optimization is.  For high level issues, (identifying slow algorithms), it will probably be fine to profile on one platform and the results will be useful on all platforms (as will the resulting improvements).  However if you need to dig down to low level issues (assembly, cache optimizations, etc) those will be platform specific and you'll need to work on each platform individually.